# Prove the convergence of $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \frac{23^n}{n^{13}} \cdot \frac{1}{6}$

Tags: analysis, limits, convergence-divergence

I have to check for the limit of

$$\frac{7^n+23^n-3(11)^n+5^n}{n^2+3n^7+6n^{13}+1}$$

By factorig out $\frac{23^n}{n^{13}}$ and appying the limes to the remaining factor one gets:

$$\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \frac{23^n}{n^{13}} \cdot \frac{1}{6}$$

But I miserably fail getting the limit of that...

Can anyone help me out of there?
Thank you very much!
FunkyPeanut

P.S.: I am sorry for being brief here. I am forced to write this using my mobile phone.

Comment: Proving convergence of this sequence will be difficult, given that it diverges to positive infinity!

Comment: Nope. Can't make it converge. Try euler. he might help.

Comment: Wow... Okay. And how would I see that?

Comment: Apply L'Hospital rule ! :)

Comment: @FunkyPeanut $23^n$ grows faster than $n^{13}$. if that isn't obvious, try L'hospital 13 times. (not actually, but imagine. ) denominator becomes $13!$ numerator still stays infinite.

Comment: Or, instead of applying L'Hopital's rule 13 times, consider the answer you've been given below.

Comment: @NicholasR.Peterson that is what i meant when i said "obvious" with habit you just know exponential functions grow faster.

Comment: Oh nice! I just didn't niw that L'Hispital is also applyable on sequences. Thank you very mich this is awesome! Thise answers came in like 2 minutes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}\frac{23^n}{n^{13}} \cdot \frac{1}{6}=∞$

Because the numerator grows faster then the denominator

Answer (score 1):

Take logarithm:
$$
\lim_{n \to \infty} (n \ln 23 - 13 \ln n) = \infty
$$
So your limit is $\infty$.

Comment: the way it's written it is $\infty - \infty$. If you imply that $\frac{\log n }{n} \to 0$ in $n$, then it's the same argument as in the original question